# How to use the word "regal"?

Tags: word-usage

Definition of *regal* by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/regal):

> very special and suitable for a king or queen

Definition of *royal* by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/royal):

> belonging or connected to a king or queen or a member of their family

***"Such propaganda was significant at the time, since papal reform would soon be trying to damage regal imagery."***

Essentially, *regal* is another adjective of *royal*. What is the difference if I use "royal" instead? And it seems like it is more restricted to use *regal* compared to *royal*. So in what circumstance is the word *regal* appropriate and suitable?

Answer (score 2):

**royal** means belonging to or about **royalty**, not all royalty refers to queens and kings. It refers to all those who have titles making them a member of the royalty such as members of a royal family, dukes, duchesses, earls, etc. Also known as nobles: noblemen and noblewomen [too many to list here].

Whereas regal is relating to the king or queen, from the Latin rex for king. [queen is regina].

regal imagery is that for kings and queens or imagery that appears grandiose like that of a king or queen.

- He had **a regal appearance**w. [He looked **like a king**]
- He had a **royal appearance**. [He looked l**ike a nobleman, a member of the royalty]**

Comment: I disagree that all dukes, duchesses, etc. fall under the term **royal** or that it's a synonym for **noble**.  You are correct to mention the **royal family**, but [the definition of **royal**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/royal) is "descended from or related to a king or line of kings."  Just being part of the nobility is not sufficient to be called **royal**.  When the British press uses the term "the Royals," that's a catch-all term for everyone related to the queen by blood or marriage. They use the term "the peerage" as a catch-all term for all nobility.

Comment: Royal is an adjective and a  noun. I am not confusing them. You are. He has a royal bearing=like royalty. Not:he looks like some Royal or other. I stand by my explanation with the adjectival use of regal and royal. It is correct.

Comment: I'm not quibbling about adjective or noun, I'm disagreeing with the statement that **royalty** is "also known as nobles." That's not true.  The [wikipedia article about dukes in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukes_in_the_United_Kingdom) makes it very clear that there are both "non-royal dukes" (who are not related to the Queen) and "royal dukes" (who are related to the Queen).  All dukes are noble.  Not all dukes are royal.

Comment: I said such as members of a royal family.  I didn't say all dukes are royals. But some are. The main point I covered in my sentences: royal appearance versus regal. royalty and nobility there would be the same thing.Whereas regal means only king-like or queen-like.

Comment: I still disagree that "royalty and nobility are the same thing." Just like "regal," the word "royal" also traces its roots to the Latin word for king, specifically by way of the French *roial*, meaning "of the king (*roi*)."  It's just that in English, "royal" has come to mean "related to the king," while "regal" means "of the king."

Answer (score 0):

**Regal** is descriptive of something that is *like* or *suitable* for royalty. An example from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regal) is

> He held himself with a regal bearing, and strode forth without
>   hesitation.

**Royal** describes the *identity* of a person or thing. An example from Oxford Dictionary is

> The Queen is not the only member of the royal family to have personal
>   flags.

Note that being a king does not means he always behaves regally. After a rough night out he might be far from regal, but is still royal.

Comment: a regal bearing is a king-like or queen-like manner or bearing. Not something "suitable for royalty". A duke is royalty and if he has a regal bearing, he is "competing" with this king...

Comment: @Lambie I wrote "*like* royalty" and also "*suitable for* royalty". Walking "in a regal manner" would be "suitable for royalty".

Comment: **Oxford Dictionary** for *royal* [adj]: 1.3 Of a quality or size suitable for a king or queen; splendid

Comment: @WeatherVane, ohh, it would be great if you could elaborate that in your answer.

Comment: @XPMai done that.

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is the difference if I use "royal" instead?

A: There's no difference.

As [wiktionari](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/regal) tells us, the word regal is a [doublet](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#doublet) of royal. See its etymology:

> From Middle English regal, borrowed from Old French regal (“regal, royal”), from Latin rēgālis (“royal, kingly”), from rex (“king”); also regere (“to rule”).